# Call to a member function format() on integer datetime

Tags: rest, api, symfony, postman

I'm trying to POST an entry to db through REST API through POSTMAN. I'm using symfony framework.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": [
            {
                "message": "Error: Call to a member function format() on integer",
                "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joel\\proj3\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Types\\DateTimeType.php",
                        "line": 53,
                        "args": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the code:

```
<?php

namespace AcsUserBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use AcsUserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;

class UserController extends FOSRestController
{


   /**
 * @Rest\Post("/user/")
 */
 public function postAction(Request $request)
 {
   $data = new User;
   $personid = $request->get('personid');
   $privilagevalueid = $request->get('privilagevalueid');
   $username = $request->get('username');
   $password = $request->get('password');



   $createdate = strtotime($request->get('createdate'));



 if(empty($personid) || empty($privilagevalueid) || empty($username)|| empty($password)|| empty($createdate))
 {
   return new View("NULL VALUES ARE NOT ALLOWED", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE); 
 } 



  $data->setPersonid($personid);
  $data->setPrivilagevalueid($privilagevalueid);
  $data->setUsername($username);
  $data->setPassword($password);
  $data->setCreatedate($createdate);



  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($data);
  $em->flush();
  return new View("User Added Successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
 }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `setCreatedate` setter waiting a DateTime object.

You can change your `$createdate` variable like that;

```
$createdate = new \DateTime($request->get('createdate'));
```

Comment: Man.....You are such a life saver... The DB is getting updated. Thanxx so much bruh..... :D

Answer (score 1):

Unless your date format like Y-m-d , you will get an error this solution.

```
$createdate = new \DateTime($request->get('createdate'));
```

You should know your date format and you can use options below.

```
$createDate = $request->get('createdate');

$createDateObj = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $createDate);
$createDateObj = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $createDate);
$createDateObj = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $createDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to get data from request manually and create entity. For this you can use form and you will also have validation as bonus :)

```
public function postTeamAction(Request $request)
{
    $postData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $newTeam = new Team();
    $form = $this->createForm(TeamType::class, $newTeam);
    $form->submit($postData);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this
            ->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->persist($newTeam)
        ;
        $this
            ->->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->flush()
        ;

    }
```

In the form you can define what type every field should be.

Comment: man.. im in the starting stage of programming.. dont know how to implement this code... :) ...heheh

Comment: Read this article about Forms: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html
You don't need to create form view in twig, you only need to create Form Class that will handle validation of you data and will create entity automatically from received data. ;)

Comment: you need persist already filled `$newTeam` object if form is valid.